# Connect two lines by zigzag lines

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have two points on XZ plane, **l**arger/taller point is L=(X<sub>L</sub>, Z<sub>L</sub>) and **s**maller/shorter point is S=(X<sub>S</sub>, Z<sub>S</sub>)

[image: 2 points]

By connecting L and S points to Z=0 line, I have two lines

[image: 2 lines]

I intend to connect my two lines by zigzag diagonal cross lines

[image: zig zag lines]

I need to find points L<sub>0</sub>, L<sub>1</sub>, L<sub>k</sub>, ... L<sub>N-1</sub> and also S<sub>0</sub>, S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>k</sub>, ... S<sub>N-1</sub>, S<sub>N</sub>.

I already know two points:

S<sub>0</sub> = S = (X<sub>S</sub>, Z<sub>S</sub>)

S<sub>N</sub> = (X<sub>S</sub>, 0)

[image: zig zag lines with dots: 0, 1, ..., k, ... N]

So far, I have implemented this algorithm:

```cpp
float lX, lZ = ... // "L" (larger/taller) point coordinate on (X, Z) plane
float sX, sZ = ... // "S" (smaller/shorter) point coordinate on (X, Z) plane

size_t N = 5; // N sections below S
float sZsectionLength = sZ / N; // length of each section below S

std::vector<float> sZ_dots(N+1, 0.0); // N+1 points/dots below S
for (size_t k = 0; k < N+1; ++k) {
    sZ_dots[k] = sZ - k * sZsectionLength;
}
std::vector<float> lZ_dots(N, 0.0); // N points/dots below L
for (size_t k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
    // // Each point below L is average of two points below S
    lZ_dots[k] = ( sZ_dots[k] + sZ_dots[k+1] ) / 2.0f;
}

for (size_t k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
    Line *zig = new Line();
    zig->setStartDot(sX, sZ_dots[k]);
    zig->setCloseDot(lX, lZ_dots[k]);
    linesContainer.append(zig);

    Line *zag = new Line();
    zag->setStartDot(lX, lZ_dots[k]);
    zag->setCloseDot(sX, sZ_dots[k+1]);
    linesContainer.append(zag);
}
```

The above algorithm generates the zig zags just fine. However, I wonder if there is any **faster** algorithm to generate the zig zag cross lines. Anything which I'm missing?

Comment: Do you just want to make the algorithm run faster, or use less memory, or how are you hoping to improve it?

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez Ideally, I need fastest possible algorithm

Comment: Is it possible to make linesContainer contiguous? (So it just stores `Line` objects directly, instead of using pointers?) That'd probably be the biggest speedup

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez Sure, I can test it

Comment: Ok. The other thing I can think of is that if you use a formula to generate the positions (instead of storing them in a vector), that'd also give you a speedup just because you'd avoid memory accesses

Comment: You say "arbitrary" but the pattern here is very regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement it like this:

```
struct Line
{
  Line(float x1, float z1, float x2, float z2)
    :
      m_x1(x1),
      m_z1(z1),
      m_x2(x2),
      m_z2(z2)
  {}

  float m_x1;
  float m_z1;
  float m_x2;
  float m_z2;
};

using LineContainer = std::vector<Line>;

LineContainer getZigZag(float lx, float sx, float sz, size_t sectionCount)
{
  assert(lx < sx && sz > 0.0f);

  LineContainer lines;
  auto sectionHeight = sz / sectionCount;
  for (auto i = 0; i < sectionCount; ++i)
  {
    auto sz1 = sz - sectionHeight * i;
    auto sz2 = sz - sectionHeight * (i + 1);
    auto lz = sz1 - (sz1 - sz2) / 2.0f;

    // A section.
    //
    // From S to L
    lines.emplace_back(sx, sz1, lx, lz);
    // From L to S
    lines.emplace_back(lx, lz, sx, sz2);
  }

  return lines;
}
```

and use the function like this:

```
int main()
{
  auto zigzag = getZigZag(1.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 2);
  [..]
```

As you probably noticed, I replaced three loops with a single one that creates two lines (a single section) on each iteration.

Comment: Bonus improvement: `lines.reserve(sectionCount * 2)` - you know exactly how many `emplace_back` calls are needed, so you can precisely allocate the memory up front.

Comment: Also, line `auto sz2 = sz - sectionHeight * (i + 1);` can be replaced with this one: `auto sz2 = sz1 - sectionHeight;`